# WP_List_table with form of method=GET redirects to wrong url after submit

Tags: redirect, urls, forms, wp-list-table

I am trying to implement a filter button on my wp_list_table, however I need the form where the table is called to be of method=GET so the query parameters for filtering retain their values for pagination.  Here is my code where the table is being called:

```
function calendar_menu(){
    //Prepare Table of elements
    $wp_list_table = new Calendar_List_Table();
    $wp_list_table->prepare_items();
    ?>
    
    <form method='get'>
      <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
        <?php $wp_list_table->display(); ?>
      </div>
      </form>
    <?php
  }
```

The page where this table is located at is: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=calendar-menu`

Whenever the form gets processed,it returns a blank page with the URL to:

```
wp-admin/admin.php?_wpnonce=eaeb1f772c&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dcalendar-menu&action=-1&squad-filter=Swordfish&filterit=Filter+Calendar&paged=1&action2=-1&squad-filter2=
```

Any idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 2):

Adding following code right inside `<table>` tag helped me:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page'] ?>" />
```

So what's in the `value` attr will be passed as `page` param while form sends.